# quicksort debug

Tags: c++, quicksort

Can anyone point out why this implementation of quick sort is not working, i have gone through it several times and can't seem to find the error

```
int quickPartition ( int data[], int p, int r)
{
    int x=data[r];
    int i=p-1;
    for (int j=p; j<r; j++)
    {
        if(data[j]<x)
        {
            i++;
            int temp=data[i];
            data[i]=data[j];
            data[j]=temp;
        }
        int temp=data[i+1];
        data[i+1]=data[r];
        data[r]=temp;   
    }
    i++;
    cout<<"i:"<<i<<endl;
    return i;
}

void myQuickSort(int data[], int left, int right)
{       
    if(left<right)
    {
        int q=quickPartition(data,left,right);
        myQuickSort(data,left,q-1);
        myQuickSort(data,q+1,right);
    }
}
```

the call to quicksort is simply

```
myQuickSort(anArray,0,size-1);
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? Does it not compile? Does it give you a segmentation fault? Is it not sorting properly? If it is not sorting properly, can you give an example?

Comment: I think you could do your quicksort in a simple way, by using a recursive concatenation of sorted arrays (yeah I know, not easy to read..)

Comment: any particular reason you are not using std::sort?

Comment: @sola:  what value of `size` fails?

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why would you write your own quicksort instead of using `std::sort`? (by the way for swapping values you might also want to take a look at `std::swap`).  And most importantly: how exactly does it fail?

Comment: Notice that your code moves the pivot to either the 0th or 1st slot, but after that it's just changing the ith and last element, and you're not really sorting anything.

Comment: its not sorting correctly, if you used it to sort the following arrayint anArray[size];
 anArray[0]=2;
 anArray[1]=8;
 anArray[2]=7;
 anArray[3]=1;
 anArray[4]=3;
 anArray[5]=5;
 anArray[6]=6;
 anArray[7]=4; the output is this:Element at index 0 is 2
Element at index 1 is 1
Element at index 2 is 3
Element at index 3 is 7
Element at index 4 is 4
Element at index 5 is 5
Element at index 6 is 6
Element at index 7 is 8

Comment: its for a sorting visualization using the SDL library, writing my own quick sort allows me to display the screen graphics exactly where I want them in the algorithm

Comment: May I suggest that clearer variable names (like `pivot` and `store`) coupled with comments would help people better diagnose your problems in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methinks

```
    int temp=data[i+1];
    data[i+1]=data[r];
    data[r]=temp;
```

should go outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of partition looks entirely bogus. What you want is iterate from both ends and on each end find an object which belongs to the opposite part. If the iterators meet, you are done. Otherwise you swap the two objects and find the next pair.

Personally, I can't think properly in the abstractions you are using: I have a much easier time to think in terms of iterators pointing to the respective objects and finding the next object to swap should be functions as well. Also, I need to factor things into small, comprehensible bits. You swap objects at some point. This should be a separate function. With this partition() would look something like this:

```
int* partition(int* left, int* right, int value) {
    while (left != right)
    {
         left = find_forward(left, right, value);
         right = find_backward(left, right, value);
         if (left != right)
         {
             swap(left, right);
         }
    }
    return left;
}
```

I haven't tested this but something along those lines should work. Obviously, I would just use `std::swap()` to swap elements and `std::find_if()` to find suitable locations (for the backward case using `std::reverse_iterator`). Well, if this weren't a homework assignment you would just use `std::sort()` anyway: it doesn't use a vanilla quick-sort but a variation which detects that it is running into a bad case and uses `std::heap_sort()` in this case to guarantee that it stays O(n log n).

Comment: I think his partition works alright. If you apply Daniel Fischer's modification: http://ideone.com/eBygm

Comment: @BlackJack: if you need to modify it so it works it obviously doesn't work alright ;) I see that your modification isn't dramatic but I also think that this version does too many swaps: assume that all elements are smaller than "x". It then swaps each individual element although the sequence is already properly partitioned.

Comment: Yup. It's less efficient than scanning from both ends, but it's correct.